# Dynamic Linq Select

Tags: linq, select

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the Dynamic LinQ select.  I have read Scott Gu's blog and each of the suggested posts but still cannot get my little brain to understand.  I need to query an entity object passing in a variable for the column name.  Assume an entity (table) containing 3 columns named: Mon, Tue & Wed.  These contain data for each record.  I do not know the column to hit at compile time so I need to pass a column name into the query.  How can I accomplish this either using DLink or directly using Expression Trees?

Comment: Why not to go with case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't need Dynamic LINQ for that...

```
var columniwant="Mon"; // Or "Tue" or "Wed"
var query=db.stuff here;

IQueryable<string> result;
switch(columniwant)
{
  case "Mon": result=query.Select(q=>q.Mon); break;
  case "Tue": result=query.Select(q=>q.Tue); break;
  case "Wed": result=query.Select(q=>q.Wed); break;
}
```

That said, I would think this would work:

```
var result=db.stuff here.Select(columniwant);
```